# Passing data from one component to another in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am setting Sub Domain URL's for single app. Sub domain name will enter at the first time. it saves to the async storage and need to retrieve it from a common component

Using the const, it's not working properly.

Here is the partially completed code. baseURL and socketURL is needed inside another component function. How can I access these constants from there ?

index_new.js

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    import Login from "../screens/common/login/login/login";

    export default class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                sub_domain: '',
            };
        }

        async getSchoolCode() {
            let sub_domain = '';
            try {
                sub_domain = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SCHOOL_CODE') || ''
            } catch (error) {
            }
            return sub_domain;
        };

        async setSubdomain() {
            const sub_domain = await this.getschoolcode()
            await this.setState({ sub_domain })
        }

        getBaseUrl() {
            return `http://${this.state.sub_domain}.vidhyadhan.in:81/`;
        }

        getSocketIoUrl() {
            return `http://${this.state.sub_domain}.vidhyadhan.in:8080/`;
        }

        async componentDidMount() {
            await this.setSubdomain();
        }

        render() {
            const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl();
            const socketIoUrl = this.getSocketIoUrl();
            const extraProps = {
                baseUrl,
                socketIoUrl
            }

            return (
                <View>
                    <Login {...extraProps} />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

Login.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {
        Alert,
        Keyboard,
        Text,
        View,
        TextInput,
        TouchableHighlight,
        Image,
        ActivityIndicator,
        StatusBar,
    } from 'react-native'
    import config from "../../../../config";
    import styles from './style'
    import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
    import Toaster from '../../../../components/toaster'
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

    class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                credentials: {
                    schoolcode: "",
                    email: "",
                    password: "",
                },
                loading: false,
                school_code: '',
            };
        }


        async getschoolcode() {
            let school_code = '';
            try {
                school_code = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SCHOOL_CODE') || ''
            } catch (error) {
            }
            return school_code;
        };

        updateText(text, field) {
            let newCredentials = Object.assign(this.state.credentials);
            newCredentials[field] = text;
            // setState should be done like this
            this.setState({
                credentials: newCredentials
            })

            if(field == 'schoolcode'){
                AsyncStorage.setItem('SCHOOL_CODE', text);
                this.getschoolcode().then((keyValue) => {
                    this.state.school_code = keyValue;
                    console.log(this.state.school_code);
                });
            }
        }
        async login() {
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            let credentials = this.state.credentials;
            if (this.state.credentials.schoolcode == '' || this.state.credentials.email == '' || this.state.credentials.password == '') {
                Toaster.toast('Please Enter a valid UserName and Password', '#d30000')
            } else {
                const that = this;
                credentials.email = that.state.credentials.email;
                this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
                const new_url = this.props.baseUrl;
                fetch(config.baseURL + 'mobileapi/get_token/?username=' + `${that.state.credentials.email}` + '&password=' + `${that.state.credentials.password}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        credentials: credentials,
                    }),
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then(responseJson => {
                        if (responseJson.confirmation === "success") {
                            AsyncStorage.setItem('USER_ID', responseJson.data.user_id.toString());
                            this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
                            }, 500);
                        } else {
                            this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                Toaster.toast('Please Enter a valid UserName and Password', '#d30000')
                                // throw new Error(responseJson.message);
                            }, 500);

                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {

                        //stop loading
                        this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });

                        setTimeout(() => {
                            if (JSON.stringify(err.message) === JSON.stringify('Network request failed')) {
                                Toaster.toast('Please check your internet connection or try again later', '#d30000')
                            }
                        }, 500);

                    })

            }
        }

        render() {
            const loginText = (this.state.loading) ? 'Loading' : 'Login';
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <StatusBar backgroundColor="#2383c9"
                               translucent={true}
                               hidden={false}/>
                    <Image source={require('../../../../assets/images/icons/logo.png')}
                        style={{ width: 99, height: 99, margin: 5, }} />
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, margin: 20, color: "#ffffff" }}>Vidhyadhan</Text>

                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.inputIcon}
                               source={require('../../../../assets/images/icons/username.png')} />
                        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                                   placeholder="School-Code"
                                   underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                                   onChangeText={text => {
                                       this.updateText(text, 'schoolcode')
                                   }} value={this.state.schoolcode}
                                   autoCorrect={false}
                                   autoCapitalize={"none"}
                        />
                    </View>


                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.inputIcon}
                            source={require('../../../../assets/images/icons/username.png')} />
                        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                            placeholder="Username"
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={text => {
                                this.updateText(text, 'email')
                            }} value={this.state.email}
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            autoCapitalize={"none"}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.inputIcon}
                            source={require('../../../../assets/images/icons/password.png')} />
                        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                            placeholder="Password"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={text => {
                                this.updateText(text, 'password')
                            }}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            secureTextEntry />
                    </View>

                    <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
                        onPress={this.login.bind(this)} >
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            {this.state.loading === false ?
                                <Icon name='login' type='entypo' size={16} color='white' /> :
                                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#ffffff" />}
                            <Text style={styles.loginText}> {loginText} </Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Login;
```

Comment: Please, set `js` as the language of the code block.

Can you provide more information about where's the other component? It's a child of this component?

Comment: Also, don't mutate the state as that won't re-render your component. Instead use the `useState` function:

```js
this.setState({ sub_domain: keyValue })
```

Comment: @Arol Other component is not a child component. Eg: a login screen. We enter the sub domain url to that login page. It save the sub domain to asyc storage. and then we call the above code, before the login fetch url call. So, there we construct the complete url using the sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

First, You're not setting the state correctly. Then, you're trying to set the state twice.

Here's a better way of doing it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sub_domain: '',
    };
  }

  async getSchoolCode() {
    let sub_domain = '';
    try {
      sub_domain = await AsyncStorage.getItem('sub_domain') || ''
    } catch (error) {
    }
    return sub_domain;
  };

  async setSubdomain() {
    const sub_domain = await this.getschoolcode()
    await this.setState({ sub_domain })
  }

  getBaseUrl() {
    return `http://${this.state.sub_domain}.vidhyadhan.in:81/`;
  }

  getSocketIoUrl() {
    return `http://${this.state.sub_domain}.vidhyadhan.in:8080/`;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setSubdomain();
  }

  render() {
    const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl();
    const socketIoUrl = this.getSocketIoUrl();

    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Based on the comments, here's how your render can be:

```
render() {
  const baseUrl = this.getBaseUrl();
  const socketIoUrl = this.getSocketIoUrl();
  const extraProps = {
    baseUrl,
    socketIoUrl
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <MyFirstComponent {...extraProps} />
      <MySecondComponent {...extraProps} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

And in your `MyFirstComponent`, you can either use `this.props.baseUrl` or `this.props.socketIoUrl`

Comment: First, thank you for pointing me that. I am still learning. How can I access the baseUrl from another component .? Not in the render view of another component, I want to use these const inside a function.

Comment: @JintoAntony you'll either need to pass it through your components in Props or use a state management library like `MobX` or `redux`. I suggest you strengthen your `React` skills before moving to these libraries.

Comment: Khali ok. Can you tell me how to pass it through using component in Props ? I mean an example .? What I don't know, How to take these values from another component. Thanks for pointing me to redux. I am kind of avoiding the use of redux here.

Comment: Khalili I am kind of struggling to do this. I am placing the complete code above. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Khalili I am added const new_url = this.props.baseUrl; // this is where I want to fetch the URL.

Comment: @JintoAntony based on this; I would suggest to start using MobX or Redux; or Try using `axios` for your requests and set a default baseUrl for `axios` which can also be a solution for your issue

Comment: do you have any examples, I can start. Bcoz, I am short on time, need to fix this immediately. Any other suggestions for the above code ?

Comment: @JintoAntony to be honest, I don't have any example that I can share with you right now. Sorry for that. I would suggest to check `MobX`; you can start integrating it within an hour :-)

Comment: I am going to use Redux. Looks like its the best way of approach for these. Is that ok ?